# Determine, for each film, which was the performance that income the most

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT SUM(pelicula.PrecioEntrada) AS Recaudado, funcion.NombrePelicula, funcion.IDFuncion
FROM funcion
INNER JOIN pelicula ON funcion.NombrePelicula=pelicula.Nombre
INNER JOIN entradas ON funcion.IDFuncion=entradas.IDFuncion
WHERE funcion.NombrePelicula=pelicula.Nombre
GROUP BY funcion.NombrePelicula, funcion.IDFuncion
```

Determine, for each film, which was the performance that income the most

For example, when I run the query I should get as a result, the name of each film, income and the ID of the Show,
And I get every single income of every film and its show ID.

[image: [![data] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDL1p.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDL1p.png)]

So, I should only be able to see 15000, IT, 10 because it has the most income, but I see all the shows

Answer (score 1):

Do you want a limit/top query here?

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 SUM(p.PrecioEntrada) AS Recaudado, f.NombrePelicula, f.IDFuncion
FROM funcion f
INNER JOIN pelicula p ON f.NombrePelicula = p.Nombre
INNER JOIN entradas e ON f.IDFuncion = e.IDFuncion
GROUP BY f.NombrePelicula, f.IDFuncion;
```

If there could be two or more movies tied with the highest sum of entry price, and you want to display all ties, then replace `TOP 1` with `TOP 1 WITH TIES` in the above query.

Comment: i cant use limit in microsoft sql server :(

Comment: thats ok, we are close. but i I need to ask what is the f.IDFuncion that raises the most per F.NombrePelicula

Comment: Add sample data to your question please.

Comment: for example i need [link] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDL1p.png) 15000, IT,10. 
14250, Argentina 1985, 4.
13500, Star Wars IV, 3
10500, Harry Styles, 14

Comment: We need consumable data... i.e. formatted text, not images.

Comment: what do u mean with consumable data?

Comment: Ideally DDL+DML i.e. we can copy and paste the data to test the query against it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen `TOP 1` isn't going to ensure that you the film with the most income is it? Cos its not ordered by anything? Won't it just give a random film with its income?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Oms9mZEXaJvl1rvcjeWjbhYS4HmXwWpu/view here is it all my code, the last part is my question